# How to print a cheque through the receipt printer in Java?

Tags: java, printing, receipt

I have **pos58 receipt printer**(printer made in China), this printer supports **ESC-POS Commands**. 
I want to print out a cheque in Java without JavaPos api. Just I don't know how do this.

Is there some way to implement it? Or what the library is?
Or are there any examples of that?

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this implementation after a quick web search, may help: https://code.google.com/p/escprinter/source/browse/trunk/net/drayah/matrixprinter/ESCPrinter.java?r=2