# How to print a cheque through the receipt printer in Java?

Tags: java

I have **pos58 receipt printer**(printer made in China), this printer supports **ESC-POS Commands**. 
I want to print out a cheque in Java without JavaPos api. Just I don't know how do this.

Is there some way to implement it? Or what the library is?
Or are there any examples of that?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278405/connecting-and-printing-to-a-printer-in-java

Comment: This is custom printer

Comment: And I want print cheque

Comment: There are many pos58 receipt printers from various manufacturers.  Who is the manufacturer of your printer?  This is a link to a pos58 printer programming manual: http://www.sourcecodeprojects.com/1835160/  You will wait a long time for the download.  Good luck and let us know how it goes.

Comment: Gilbert I can not download this document. Error:Recently the main download server multiple failures, leading to many download problems of registered members. We are currently upgrading and relocation of the main download server to making download return to normal as soon as possible, sorry.

Comment: Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189204/how-to-print-a-cheque-through-the-receipt-printer-in-java) Can't close this one because active bounty prevents it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to find a way to write a text stream (or even better byte stream) to the printer (this really depends how the printer is connected COM port? USB?)

I have worked with numerous POS printers over the years and once you can get ANY text at all you should find the escape codes to handle the details of paper loading etc quite easy to manage.

Comment: You can write example this, please or link tutorial

Comment: Start with telling us how the printers are connected. Is your difficulty with sending data to the printer or with handling the POS escape codes?

Comment: I don't know how to need connect to receipt printer(For example I have two connected printers(receipt printer and laser printer) in computer, need select receipt printer) and print my cheque via receipt printer.

Comment: @boyfox: Please check Glen's answer below - he seems to link to exactly what you are looking for here (and select his answer for the Bounty)

Comment: I have long seen the answer Elemental. At this answer I do not have.